# Return the difference between two lists by comparing key values, and not the entire objects in Java

Tags: java, loops, filter, java-stream

I have two lists from the same class (e.g. a Person class with a name and age property), and I am trying to come up with an efficient way to remove elements from List A, if they appear in List B, but only if the name property matches (ignoring age). I don't want to remove ALL values that have a matching name from List B, but rather remove one value from List A for every matching name in List B.

Here's an example:

```
public class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private Integer age;

    public Person(String firstName, Integer age) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.age = age;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Person p1 = new Person("John", 25);
        Person p2 = new Person("Lisa", 54);
        Person p3 = new Person("Mike", 61);
        Person p4 = new Person("John", 61);
        Person p5 = new Person("John", 13);
        List<Person> people1 = new ArrayList<Person>();
        people1.add(p1);
        people1.add(p2);
        people1.add(p3);
        people1.add(p4);
        people1.add(p5);

        Person p6 = new Person("John", 88);
        Person p7 = new Person("Lisa", 66);
        Person p8 = new Person("Mike", 71);
        List<Person> people2 = new ArrayList<Person>();
        people2.add(p6);
        people2.add(p7);
        people2.add(p8);


        for (Person p : people2) {
            people1.stream()
                .filter(person -> Boolean.parseBoolean(person.firstName = p.firstName))
                .findFirst()
                .ifPresent(person -> people1.remove(person));
        } // This is what i've tried, but it doesn't work and seems very inefficient

        System.out.println(people1);
    }
```

Basically, I want to iterate through the `people2` list, and if a person with the same name exists in the `people1` list, then find the first match and remove it (only caring about name, not age).

Desired Result: A list containing

- John, 61
- John, 13

Comment: Strings should be compared with `equals`, not with `=`. Nothing is compared with `=`.

Comment: Why not use `HashMaps` instead of Lists? Then the lookups and removals are *O(1)* and the whole thing becomes linear.

Comment: `person.firstName = p.firstName` is an *assignment*; it changes the variable `person.firstName` to point to the same string as `p.firstName`. I leave as an exercise for you to find out what `Boolean.parseBoolean(…)` is really for and why it isn’t appropriate here. As a general advice: don’t insert code into your program whose purpose you don’t understand.

Comment: Step 1: count the occurrences of names in the second list (into a mutable map): `Map<String,Integer> counts = people2.stream() .collect(Collectors.toMap(Person::getFirstName, p -> 1, Integer::sum, HashMap::new));` Step 2: remove each person from the first list if their count is still not negative after decrementing: `people1.removeIf(p -> counts.merge(p.getFirstName(), -1, Integer::sum) >= 0);` That’s it. This example assumes that you have a method like `public String getFirstName() { return firstName; }` in your `Person` class as the `firstName` field is `private`.

Comment: https://ideone.com/QmqCpE

Answer (score 0):

The main efficiency problem you have is 2 nested loops, resulting in O(n<sup>2</sup>) [time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity).

However, you can do it O(n) time complexity by using a more efficient way to find the matching person from `people1` to remove.

```
Map<String, Deque<Person>> map = people1.stream().collect(groupingBy(Person::getFirstName, toCollection(ArrayDeque::new)));

for (Person p : people2) {
    Optional.ofNullable(map.get(p.getFirstName()))
      .filter(list -> !list.isEmpty())
      .ifPresent(Deque::remove);
}

people1 = map.values().stream().flatMap(Deque::stream).toList();
```

This creates a map (actually as `HashMap`, which has constant time efficiency) to find the list of people with the same first name. The lists are `LinkedList`, which has O(1) time complexity for removing the first element.

Then, for each person in list 2, the list of people with the same first name is retrieved from the map and if it exists and is not empty, the first person is removed from it.

At the end of the loop, list 1 is constructed from whatever people remain in the map.

This algorithm scales linearly (both time and space).

Comment: *"This algorithm would scale linearly."* - But it is worth noting that it also requires `O(N)` additional space.

Comment: @StephenC OK, but only references to already created objects are held in the map, (plus entries, but they too have a tiny footprint) so O(tiny N) space

Comment: The footprint of a `Map.Entry` is significantly more than a reference.  It is 3 references + an `int` + an object header.  (For a 64 bit JVM without compressed OOPS, it is 40 bytes per entry, I think.)  And then there is the `HashMap`'s hash array whose size is proportional to the number of entries (until N gets too large).  And the `ArrayList<Person>` value objects which comprise a Java object with a private primitive array.  It could add up to O(*significant* N) ... depending on your assumptions.

Comment: Since the OP’s code is not even remotely correct, it’s pointless to discuss its “main efficiency problem”. Then, the code is unnecessarily complicated, `map.getOrDefault(p.getFirstName(), null)` is not better than `map.get(p.getFirstName())` which will return `null` for absent keys anyway. Further, when the complexity is O(n * k) and you don’t know anything about the number of people with the same name (k), then it’s still O(n²), as O() denotes the *worst case*. Which could easily avoided by grouping into `ArrayDeque` instead of `ArrayList`, then, removing the first item is O(1).

Answer (score -1):

> *"... I want to iterate through the `people2` list, and if a person with the same name exists in the `people1` list, then find the first match and remove it (only caring about name, not age). ..."*

Use an *[Iterator](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Iterator.html)* to traverse each list.

```java
Iterator<Person> x = people1.iterator();
Iterator<Person> y = people2.iterator();
String s;
while (x.hasNext()) {
    s = x.next().getFirstName();
    while (y.hasNext()) {
        if (y.next().getFirstName().equals(s)) {
            x.remove();
            y.remove();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Or, if you're utilizing *Stream#filter*, use a *while-loop* for the *people2* list, so you can remove the value.

```java
people1 =
    people1.stream().filter(x -> {
        Iterator<Person> i = people2.iterator();
        String s = x.getFirstName();
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            if (i.next().getFirstName().equals(s)) {
                i.remove();
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }).toList();
```

Output

```
[John 61, John 13]
```